# Postioning rotated inline-block pseudo element

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30vh;
}

span{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2vw;
  margin: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#name:before {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "I AM";
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin-right: -10vw;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<head><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span id="name">
  test
  </span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb">
  Hello</span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb_two">
  World!</span>
  
</div>
</body>
```

I am trying to vertically rotate an inline-block :before element and position it on the side of a span. So, I want the "I AM" text to be of the same width as the length of the "t" from "test" and want it to be postioned on the side with the same base level as "test". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One posibility, playing with writing mode:

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15vw;
}

span{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2vw;
  margin: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#name:before {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "I AM";
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  writing-mode: vertical-rl; 
  font-size: 7vw;
  margin-right: -4vw;
  font-weight: lighter;
  left: -2vw;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 15vw;
  padding: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<head><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span id="name">
  test
  </span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb">
  Hello</span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb_two">
  World!</span>
  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I didn't even know about writing mode. :D

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30vh;
}

span{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2vw;
  margin: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
#name{
 margin-left: 32px;
}
#name:before {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "I AM";
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-right: -10vw;
    font-weight: lighter;
    left: calc(-5%);
    top: -14px;
    font-size: 11vh;
}
```

```html
<head><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span id="name">
  test
  </span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb">
  Hello</span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb_two">
  World!</span>
  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can give margin-left: 25px; to arrange it in same order.

Answer (score 0):

Changed some css properties of `name:before` class.

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30vh;
}

span{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2vw;
  margin: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#name:before {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "I AM";
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size:10vh;
  left:4vw;
  bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<head><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span id="name">
  test
  </span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb">
  Hello</span>
  <br />
  <span id="verb_two">
  World!</span>
  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, I want the "I AM" text to be of the same width as the length of the "t" from "test". I think you missed that part.

Comment: I want the font-weight to be lighter than the rest. @vals' solution worked for me. Thanks btw, :D

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part,,I have updated my code, I don't think you need `writing-mode` property.